# When is $\mathbf E = -\nabla V$ is wrong?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

So I came across this problem where the potential of a point $V=0$, but $\mathbf E$ is not $0$.

Specifically this problem:

[image]

If we use the formula $v = -\int \mathbf E \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf l = 0$ it is correct, but when you use $\mathbf E = -\nabla V = 0$, it is wrong.
So can anyone explain why is $\mathbf E = -\nabla V$ wrong here and in general?

Comment: Hi Peter, can you tell just a bit more about your problem ? I assume you have 2 point charges separated by a distance d. If you do the integration: along wich direction $\vec{l}$ do you go ? In general it is easily accomplished to have the potential to be zero V=0 since you can always add a constant without changing the forces or the electrical field in this case.

Comment: To say $E=0$ at a point because $V=0$ at that point makes no sense; the behaviour of $V$ around that point is crucial. You wouldn't say $2x$ has to be $0$ wherever $1-x^2=0$.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the potential of a point V=0, but E is not 0.

No contradiction there.

Consider this analogy. V is analogous to altitude. So V=0 is true for points at sea level. grad V ( or -E) is analogous to the slope of a landscape. So grad V = 0 is true for points on level ground. There is no requirement that all points on level ground are at sea level, nor that all points at sea level are on level ground.